# How to insert image in database using Struts 2 <s:file> tag

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, file-upload, struts2

I want to insert image in database in Struts 2 application;

I am using  three classes:

1. Model class
2. DAO class to insert query using prepared statement.
3. Action class

In JSP I am using `<s:file>` tag .

My question is: what type of model class private variable I need to use?

In database I am using `BLOB` type to store image, is it right? If not please give me suggestions.

How to insert images in database using Srtuts 2?

Answer (score 4):

For uploading files to Struts 2 you are already using Struts 2 FileUpload Interceptor and all you need to define these fields in your action or Model class

```
public class UploadAction extends ActionSupport {
      private File file;
      private String contentType;
      private String filename;

      public void setUpload(File file) {
         this.file = file;
      }

      public void setUploadContentType(String contentType) {
         this.contentType = contentType;
      }

      public void setUploadFileName(String filename) {
         this.filename = filename;
      }

      public String execute() {
         //...
         return SUCCESS;
      }
 }
```

You can convert your `File` data to `byteArray` by something like

```
IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream input);
```

and can save that as a `Blob` in your database by something like

```
Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
blob.setBytes(1, bytes);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the three parameters need to have the same prefix (http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/FileUploadInterceptor.html) and that the N of fileName must be capitalized: then `file`, `fileContentType` and `fileFileName`

Comment: @AndreaLigios  though i am a bit agree with your, but i just took code snippet from http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/file-upload.html and more over OP can take care of this

Comment: I didn't noticed the Setters different from the variable names... then It works like this, but it's not Javabeans compliant :/ Strange examples in the documentation :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Agree with you , even I just copied that code believing that everything if OK :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`fileUpload` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload-interceptor.html) you can get the `File` object into your action when you submit the form that contains `<s:file>` tags and value data that able to transfer to the server. If your uploading succeeds then you able to read that data on the server from the local store i.e. `java.io.tempdir` may be used to set the location of the local store. Then you need to read the contents of the file

```
File file; //this is uploaded file

FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
is.read(data);
is.close();
```

Then you can use `java.sql.Blob` or `java.sql.Clob` type to write the data to save in the database the type should correspond to the database field type, i.e. BLOB for blobs, CLOB for clobs, etc. When you retrieve the data again from the db the same java sql type will be used to convert data back.

Now to your question if you want to keep that value in the model that you want to populate with the database data there's two options:

1. Keep the data as is, i.e. `java.sql.Blob`
2. Convert it to `byte[]`

for the second choice you'll need to something like `byte[] data = getBytes(File file)` that opens a stream and reads the data from file, or if you have `Blob` then use `blob.getBytes(pos, length)`.

In the first choice you have deal with streams, use `Blob`s `setBinaryStream(pos)`  to get the output stream to write the uploaded file data, or `getBinaryStream()` to retrieve  data from database.

In the most cases you should use the second choice until you have enough reasons to use the first one.

Examples to store the [Blob](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/blob.html) to the database using JDBC API you could find [Adding and Retrieving BLOB Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html#add_retrieve_blob).

There's also good example from [Inserting Image in Database Table](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/insert-image-in-mysql.shtml).