# How to intercept an image file uploading with CKEditor in Struts 2

Tags: java, file-upload, struts2, ckeditor, struts2-jquery

I have a `CKEditor` on different pages of the site, so I settled up the uploads to `true` and all the configuration stuff for it to work, and the image upload worked just fine for `"Send it to the Server"` tab. But from here I want to intercept or interact with `upload` function to be able to upload images not to a folder, but into database with some flags like `"page"` where is image uploaded, `"category"`, `"cropping"` and some another manipulations with them.

**So how could it be done to intercept this uploads?**

I was curious and I found that the default action for uploads is

```
/%project_name%/ckeditor/upload.html?CKEditor=textarea_1457018535&CKEditorFuncNum=2&langCode=en
```

and the action for this uploads is [CkeditorUpload.java](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/trunk/struts2-jquery-richtext-plugin/src/main/java/com/jgeppert/struts2/jquery/richtext/actions/CkeditorUpload.java?r=1375), but I don't realize how can I use them further.

Comment: Will not work to intercept, means you don't need to write an interceptor for it. But have to write implementation. What did you try?

Comment: By "intercept" I didn't mean to write an interceptor, but to INTERCEPT that action of upload whatever it is AJAX request or Struts action or something else.

Comment: Do you mean that *intercept* is to bypass the action execution or what?

Comment: hmm, not so much bypass, but to overwrite (override) it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you'd like to override it you should start overriding the method `execute` from the action class above.

Also override the configuration by replacing the class reference in the action configuration. The point is where the original implementation creates `FileOutputStream` should be replaced to `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Then let it write to the byte array stream and `getBytes()` from it will give you `byte[] data`. Save that data to the database.

You may also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16192843/573032) answer will help you to do it.

[This](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-save-image-into-database/) tutorial will explain you how to do it with Hibernate.

Then the code where the action writes HTML change the disk path to the action path `/uploads` mapping to the action which retrieves the image from the database. Example of the `ImageAction` you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30687378/573032).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18001916/573032) answer will also be helpful.

Comment: thanks for that. The only point I want to know is how to interact with CKEditor's image upload, otherwise I don't have any problems with saving it to the database, but thanks anyway. The defaultStack in my configuration has <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>, how I can get the data from there now? or I need to configure some sort of a listener?

Comment: The `upload` property should be populated with this interceptor.

Comment: I think I can't get the right point of your idea, I find it hard to understand what you're trying to say, sorry for that.

Comment: May be [this](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/file-upload-interceptor.html) explains better? How to interact, did you use their showcase? Image properties contains a tab upload and you can upload it on server via a button then press ok and uploaded image linked to the text. I have uploaded two images there and links are valid but it doesn't show donowhy.

Comment: CKEditor uses his own action for Uploading files which is integrated in the library itself, I don't have access there, if I do had I didn't asked for this ever.