# How to get filename selected from file dialog in JSP and Struts action class?

Tags: java, html, jsp, file-upload, struts2

I am developing a web application in which for User Registration the user has to select a profile picture and then click on upload button.

So, my question is how to get `FileName` which user has selected and display.

I am using Struts 2 and JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the property `uploadFileName` along with `upload` property to the action that accepts uploading a file, i.e. the [`fileUpload` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/file-upload-interceptor.html) is applied to the action configuration then it will be populated. There's also `uploadContentType` attribute that could be populated.

```
private File upload;
private String uploadContentType;
private String uploadFileName;
//getters ans setters assumed
```

in the JSP use the `name` attribute to map it to the action

```
<s:file name="upload"/>
```

Comment: Hey I am using your appraoch bt I am getting nullPointerException for following statement-  String filePath=servletRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");    Here getSession is giving null value. I checked all code but where session is going null cant recognize...!

Comment: Try `ServletActionContext.getServletContext()`.

Comment: Hello, I have another doubt. Actually the statement which given i.e. getSession is still giving null value.So I decided not to waste time. So I am now uploading image in D drive and its working great ,but while displaying that image in jsp,it is trying to retrieve it from context path where image does not exist. So my question is how i should change my code to retrieve that image from D:\\ . Is there any solution?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20176879/573032) answer and follow the links.

Answer (score 0):

if The input tag you are using in your html is

```
<input type="file" name="MyFile" id="MyFile" />
```

then you can retrieve your file name in javascript by using the following code

```
var fileName = document.getElementById('MyFile').value;
```

But for some security reasons, browsers won't allow you retrieve full filepath of your file.

But I heard old versions of Internet Explorer gives you file path.

Good Luck!

Comment: Yes I was planning to use this approach ,but for the same reason I am not using it.I may use Struts default facility. Thanks for your concern.